# Node.js Express: re-accessing variables injected into .html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom, express

I am using node.js/express and EJS (embedded javascript).

I inject some variables into an .html page like this

```
res.render('userHome.html', {
                user : user,
                teams : teams,
                user_db_name : user_db_name
            });
```

userHome.html contents:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SASC Sparks Lineup Generator</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancy_scripts/userHomeController.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form  onsubmit="chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate(<%=user._id%>)" id="page1">
        <!-- <input id="createNewTeam" type="submit" value="Create New Team"/> -->
        <button type="submit" value="Create New Team" id="createNewTeamButton">Create New Team</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate.js file contents

```
$( document ).ready(function() {});


function chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate(user_id){

      //I want user_id to be passed into this method, but this does not work

    console.log($.document);

    if (window.confirm("Do you wish to import team data from an existing roster?")) { 
        window.location.replace("/users/" + user_id + "/importNewTeamRoster", "Importing new roster");
//        window.open("/users/" + user_id + "/importNewTeamRoster", "Importing new roster");
        }
    else{
        window.location.replace("/users/" + user_id + "/importNewTeamRoster", "Importing new roster");
    }
};
```

*trying to inject <%=user._id%> into chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate() is making me feel a little silly because I know that's probably ridiculously wrong.

how can I get the user_id to be passed into chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate() and then once I am in chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate() how do I access the variable? Perhaps the user variable is attached to the document/window DOM objects?

Answer (score 1):

Find out somehow how this is being rendered into the page:

`<form  onsubmit="chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate(<%=user._id%>)" id="page1">`

Suppose `<%=user._id%>` is a String containing 'lk45jqlk43jakljf' which is a database key for a particular user.

Now *think*:

- How does String normally get rendered in a page by a template handler?
- With quotes or without quotes?

Did you answer [*without quotes*](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)?  Hopefully, you did.  Why does that matter?

Well, the form will then call

```
chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate(lk45jqlk43jakljf)
```

Does that look OK? Maybe?

It would be if `lk45jqlk43jakljf` were a *variable name*.  But, it is not.  It is a *literal value* that you want to assign to the formal parameter `user_id`, and so it needs quotes inside the parenthesis, like 
`'lk45jqlk43jakljf'`.   When there is a submit, you want this call, with quotes:

```
chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate('lk45jqlk43jakljf')
```

Since the line that is being rendered already uses double quotes, we must use single quotes here like so:

`<form  onsubmit="chooseImportTeamOrManualCreate('<%=user._id%>')" id="page1">`

so that whatever `user._id` is, it gets quotes when it is rendered into the form.

Sometimes someone sticks you with awful code that just has to work, and there is no time allotted to refactor it properly.  Still,  code like this seems ripe for an extended refactoring project. Two things stand out here as "bad code smell":

1. Setting an event handler in HTML or templates that become HTML.  Instead, use JS or jQuery.  See, for example, [these jQuery coding standards, under Events #5](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/) where the author writes:

> DO NOT use behavioral markup in HTML (JavaScript inlining), these are debugging nightmares. > Always bind events with jQuery to be consistent so it's easier to attach and remove events > dynamically.
>
> `<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="myEventHandler();">my link</a> <!-- BAD -->`

Don't use jQuery? Fine.  Setting events in plain Javascript is still better than setting onSomething properties of elements in an HTML string, for the same reasons.

The next person to work on it, which may be you, has to do a lot more searching to find the relevant bits of code and what they do, observe multiple formatting rules, etc... problems which go away when the code is structured more towards common practice.

2. Embedding Javascript variable data in HTML or templates that become HTML.  This is really simply a repeat of the same issues as above.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your last few sentences make a little bit of sense, but an example (link?) would be very helpful.

Comment: Also @Paul, is the injected variable attached to the DOM document itself? That would be a work around, and maybe that relates to the AJAX solution.

Comment: The client code on any page of your app ought to know its `userid` somehow.  The question is how.  localStorage looks pretty good if you are comfortable supporting mostly HTML 5, because once set it is just there, even after a refresh.  Of course, that doesn't answer the question of how it gets there in the first place, and it clearly needs to come from the server with the page rather than be requested anonymously.  So maybe my comments on AJAX are not apropos to setting the userid.

Comment: Setting a GLOBAL like `<script>window.USERID = '<% userid %>'</script>` is a lot clearer than big hunk of code + a bunch of `<button onclick="callSomething('<% userid %>');"` + more big hunks of code because the calling syntax is simpler and all the handler functions can look for `window.USERID` in their own definitions.